# jsp image shows up on Eclipse's Web Page Editor, but not while running

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlet-filters

I am trying to insert an image to a jsp page. It shows up correctly when I link to an absolute path. However, when I try to give a relative path, the image will show up in the Web Page Editor, but doesn't show up when I actually run the Dynamic Web Project. 
Don't know if it's related or not, but the same problem occurs with the paragraph - on the Web Page Editor it's aligned to the center, but while running it shows up on the left, as if I haven't aligned it.
I'm working on Eclipse, using tomcat 5.5. Tried to view on both Explorer and Firefox, on two different computers.

```
    <p align=center>
    <img src="/logo.gif"/>
    //
    // some code
    //
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turnes out the problem was actually with my filter. I had to specify that it should always allow access to gif files.